# If an image/file is changed, does the header expire?

Tags: apache, http-headers, browser-cache

This is probably  a dumb question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I recently added mod_deflate and cache control to my htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js|css)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
```

My question was, if I update a CSS sheet, will my visitors' browser figure out that it's been modified or will it completely ignore it and won't grab it again until it expires (a week after) ?

Thanks